# Issue on the vertical align of minitabulars inside a general tabular

Tags: latex, xelatex

I provide a MWE of the case. I was working on a way to vertically align at the bottom the minitabulars in each cell of the second row except for the one containing "Casos" (which should be centered vertically in the space available), but unfortunately I was not able to do so. Perhaps there is another way around it. It would be appreciated not inserting other packages to the document, as these may conflict other parts of my local file.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\geometry{%
inner=2cm,outer=2cm,
top=2cm,bottom=2cm,
}

\usepackage{booktabs,array,graphicx,xcolor,multicol,multirow,lipsum}

\newcommand{\minitabi}[1]{\centering\FormatStyleii\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}>{\centering}p{\dimexpr(\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth)\relax}@{}} \hline #1 \\ \hline \end{tabular}}

\newcommand{\minitabii}[1]{\FormatStylei\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}>{\centering}p{\dimexpr(\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth)\relax}@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}

\newcommand{\FormatStylei}{\bfseries\fontsize{16pt}{19pt}\selectfont}

\newcommand{\FormatStyleii}{\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont}



\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
        \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.1em}
        \centering
        \typeout{thelinewidth: \the\linewidth ...}
        \typeout{thetextwidth: \the\textwidth ...}
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2mm}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}|*{6}{p{\dimexpr(\textwidth-12\tabcolsep-7\arrayrulewidth)/6\relax}|}@{}}

            \hline
            \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{%
                \minitabii{
                \hline TABLA \ref{tab:B4.1a} \\ 
                Razones Ancho-Espesor: Elementos en Compresión. \\ 
                Miembros sometidos a Flexión \\
                \hline } } \\

            \hline
            & \minitabi{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Casos}}
            & \minitabi{Descripción del Elemento}
            & \minitabi{Razón Ancho Espesor}
            & \minitabi{Razón Ancho Límite-a- \\ Espesor $\lambda_r$ \\ (esbelto / no esbelto)}
            & \minitabi{Ejemplo} \\
            
            \end{tabular}
\label{tab:B4.1a}
\end{table}

\lipsum[4]


\end{document}
```

[image]

I have tried playing with the vertical positioning of tabulars in each cell, but this does not work (i.e. using either t, m or b). Also often receive the "noalign" error when employing the command \hline at the end of a tabular, not quite sure why. The script has been compiled using xelatex. Final question, is it possible to indicate a reference to the table inside the current tabular environment as indicated?

Comment: Try `\rotatebox[origin=tr]{90}{...}`

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code for your table.

I simply changed column to a regular `p{}`-type as well as used top alignments of all inner tabulars.

`cellspace` is an addition to keep minimal spacing around rows. `\raisebox` is alter tabulars' baselines because of extra spacing above inner tables once inner rules are used.

Apart from that, the code is almost the same as yours.

EDIT. I also utilise `tabularx` to avoid unnecessary calculations.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\geometry{%
  inner=2cm,outer=2cm,
  top=2cm,bottom=2cm,
}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}              % required for X-type column
\usepackage{booktabs}              % required for \heavyrulewidth
\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Package: cellspace
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{\tabcolsep}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\tabcolsep}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}

% Package: array
\newcolumntype{P}{%
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}%
  p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\dimexpr\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth}}

% User defined
\newcommand{\FormatStylei}{\bfseries\fontsize{16pt}{19pt}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\FormatStyleii}{\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont}
\newcommand\minitabi[1]{%
  \FormatStyleii
  \raisebox{1ex}{%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\hline#1\\\hline\end{tabular}}}
\newcommand\minitabii[1]{%
  \FormatStylei
  \begin{tabular}{@{}P@{}}\hline#1\\\hline\end{tabular}}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
  \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{\heavyrulewidth}
  \centering
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2mm}%
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| *6{>{\centering\arraybackslash}O{X}|}}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{|Oc|}{\minitabii{%
    TABLA refXXX\\
    Razones Ancho-Espesor: Elementos en Compresión.\\ 
    Miembros sometidos a Flexión}} \\
    \hline
    ~
    & \minitabi{\rotatebox[origin=tr]{90}{Casos}}
    & \minitabi{Descripción\\del\\Elemento}
    & \minitabi{Razón\\Ancho\\Espesor}
    & \minitabi{Razón\\Ancho\\Límite-a-\\Espesor $\lambda_r$\\(esbelto /\\no\\esbelto)}
    & \minitabi{Ejemplo} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \label{tab:B4.1a}
\end{table}

\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

and screenshot

[image]